# The import com.toshiba cannot be resolved-Java

Tags: ubuntu, griddb

I'm using VSCode on Ubuntu version 22.04.2, to implement and run some tests according to the GridDB docs available on https://docs.griddb.net/gettingstarted/java/#schema-creation, but I'm unable to run the code because of the following error:

**"The import com.toshiba cannot be resolved-Java"**

My Java file is:

```
import com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.*;

public class GridDbTests{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("notificationAddress", "239.0.0.1");
        props.setProperty("notificationPort", "31999");
        props.setProperty("clusterName", "defaultCluster");
        props.setProperty("user", "admin");
        props.setProperty("password", "admin");
        GridStore store = GridStoreFactory.getInstance().getGridStore(props);
    }
}
```

And the lauch.json file is:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "java",
            "name": "GridDbTests.java",
            "request": "launch",
            "mainClass": "GridDbTests"
        }
    ]
}
```

What i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Well, `com.toshiba` is not a package thats contained the the JRE or JDK, but a 3rd party dependency.

The GridDB documentation tells you to compile the code manually, using

```
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/usr/share/java/gridstore.jar
$ javac Sample1.java
```

However, VSCode will not know about this. According to the VSCode documentation under https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-project, you can add the `gridstore.jar` by following these steps:

> **Manage dependencies for unmanaged folder**
> If your project is an unmanaged folder without any build tools. You can manage the dependencies by clicking the + icon or the - icon on the Referenced Libraries node or the items under it, or you can just directly drag your jar libraries to the node Referenced Libraries.

## Dependency Management

The better solution will be to properly learn how to use a dependency management tool, for example Maven.

The aforementioned VSCode documentation already contains information about Maven, and the GridDB documentation also has a page on how to use GridDB with Maven:

https://griddb.net/en/blog/using-maven-to-develop-griddb-applications/

Basically, you need to manually register the jar with Maven via

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=/usr/share/java/gridstore.jar -DgroupId=com.toshiba.mwcloud \
    -DartifactId=gs -Dversion=4.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```

And then add the following to your `pom.xml` (in the `dependencies` section):

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.toshiba.mwcloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>gs</artifactId>
        <version>4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

VSCode will usually automatically pick up changes to the `pom.xml`, if it does not, right click rhe project and hit <kbd>Maven</kbd> / <kbd>Reload Project</kbd>